# How to change the filesystem label on the vfat filesystem located on device /dev/sdb1?

Tags: filesystems, formatting, rename, usb-storage

I just followed the instructions from Cyberciti.biz to [format my Kingston USB drive](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-format-usb-pen-drive/).

Instead of ext2, I formatted the drive to vfat. I forgot to use the naming option when using `mkfs.vfat` (webpage doesn't mention it) and when I try to use `mren` I get:

```
sudo mren /dev/sdb1 KINGSTON
Can't open /dev/fd0: No such device or address
Cannot initialize 'A:'
```

Is there a way to rename the file system or do I just have to wait until the next time I reformat it?

Comment: Related on Unix.SE: [How to change the volume name of a FAT32 filesystem?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/44095/50602)

Answer (score 21):

You're looking for `dosfslabel`.

In most distributions, it can be found in the `dosfstools` package.

Comment: When I try that command I get:
bash: dosfslabel: command not found

How do you get dosfslabel?

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu 8.04 Hardy.

Comment: @snooper sudo apt-get install dosfstools

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
> sudo -i
> apt-get install apt-file
> apt-file update
> apt-file search dosfslabel

dosfstools: /sbin/dosfslabel
dosfstools: /usr/share/man/man8/dosfslabel.8.gz
dosfstools-dbg: /usr/lib/debug/sbin/dosfslabel
manpages-fr-extra: /usr/share/man/fr/man8/dosfslabel.8.gz
```

Answer (score 1):

As others said, the package is indeed [dosfstools](https://github.com/dosfstools/dosfstools), but the program might be called `fatlabel` and not `dosfslabel`.